# Javascript Banner Swap

Tags: javascript

The section is foo.com/agriculture.  It has a banner image corresponding to the name in the javascript. I need the internal page foo.com/agriculture/harvest to have a separate banner than the foo.com/agriculture. The script I am working with for the banner swap for each page is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var dir = location.pathname.split("/")[1]; 
//var dir2 = location.pathname;
if (dir == "agriculture")        
document.write('<IMG SRC="/images/ib_agriculture.jpg" WIDTH=1024 HEIGHT=91 BORDER=0>')  
else if (dir == "showcase")
document.write('<IMG SRC="/images/ib_show.jpg" WIDTH=1024 HEIGHT=91 BORDER=0>')  
else if (dir == "contact")      
document.write('<IMG SRC="/images/ib_contact.jpg" WIDTH=1024 HEIGHT=91 BORDER=0>')   
else if (dir == "distribution")     
</script>
```

I tried the following different codes to try and assign the internal page foo.com/agriculture/harvest a separate banner.

```
var dir = location.pathname.split("/")[1]; 
//var dir2 = location.pathname;
if (dir == "agriculture/harvest")        
document.write('<IMG SRC="/images/ib_agriculture_harvest.jpg" WIDTH=1024 HEIGHT=91 BORDER=0>')  
else if (dir == "showcase") 

var dir = location.pathname.split("/")[1]; 
//var dir2 = location.pathname;
if (dir == "harvest")        
document.write('<IMG SRC="/images/ib_agriculture_harvest.jpg" WIDTH=1024 HEIGHT=91 BORDER=0>')  
else if (dir == "showcase")
```

Both of the scripts above continue to grab the foo.com/agriculture banner (ib_agriculture.jpg) instead of the called foo.com/agriculture/harvest (ib_agriculture_harvest.jpg). I am not sure how to get the script to call the appropriate banner per page.

Answer (score 0):

When you call pathname.split you get an array like this:

```
["foo.com", "agriculture", "harvest"]
```

You then take the item with index 1 and put it into the `dir` variable:

```
var dir = location.pathname.split("/")[1]
```

So the value of `dir` is "agriculture", even though "harvest" is also part of the url. To check for that string you need to use `location.pathname.split("/")[2]`.

Or you can do this:

```
var parts = location.pathname.split("/");
var dir = parts[1]; 
if (parts.length > 2)
{
     dir += "/" + parts[2];
}
if (dir == "agriculture/harvest")        
     document.write('<IMG SRC="/images/ib_agriculture_harvest.jpg" WIDTH=1024 HEIGHT=91 BORDER=0>')
```

Comment: I used your second example and the image showed up on the agriculture/harvest page. However, the agriculture page does not have a banner image anymore.

Comment: @ac12 Did you add the rest of the code? For example `if (dir == "agriculture")...`